# Java how to make an entire methods call chain thread safe

Tags: java, methods, web-applications, thread-safety

I have a `method` that creates a row in a database table.

It takes *id* (let's call it **ID1**) of another table as parameter,

To asociate an *id* to the row, it calls another method to calculate it (let's call it **ID2**) from the number of rows in the table having the same month and from some other values.

Then after creating the row,

It calls another method passing **ID1** and **ID2** as parameters to create a row in a table of asociation between the above 2 tables.

Because the methods get called from number of applications (stand-alone, web service, web . . . etc.) it suffers severe data corruption as follows:

1. More than one row gets created with the same **ID2**
2. More than one row of ID2 gets associated with a single row of **ID1**

What is the best way to make this chain of methods calling thread safe to eliminate the above two bad behaviors?

### EDIT

The code is situated in a jar library, which is associated with every application

It's on oracle adf platform

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a thread safety issue, but more of a data integrity problem.
Add uniqueness constrains and make that first entry method transactional. This way you won't sacrifice performance, but will have to deal with exceptions processing and signal the failure to your clients.

Comment: I can't risk playing with the uniqueness and raise exceptions to the client if the error is from the application, I need to find another way

Comment: I see. But at least communicate the problem to your dba guys. Even if you somehow fix that in your jar, chances are it will be a partial fix.
Imagine if the change to those tables come from code outside of your control. Anything is better than corrupted data, and here the database is the last line of defense )

Comment: they are all transactional nothing to change here, the whole application is transactional based on adf platform, the commits are done only through getDBTransaction

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a thread issue; it sounds more like isolation and transaction management to me.

All the calls in the chain need to be a serialized, single unit of work.  No other thread should be able to see the database changes until all are complete.

You need a transaction manager and a database connection that is set to `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

Spring will make this easy to do.

Comment: You need a transaction manager and setting the isolation level of your database connection.

Comment: I think you're doing them in the wrong place.  Should be a single database transaction.  You designed and coded it in a less than optimal way.  Why would you recreate all the stuff that database vendors give you in HTTP web services?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have just one service which updates your database and every other service works through that.  This way you can control how the transaction and IDs are managed.

Comment: But that does not solve the multi threading problem. The op has to instantiate this service then once per incoming request or synchronize the access to it.

Comment: The code that I am taking about is unique, it's a jar library asociated with every other application to not repeat code and so every other application calls it, I need to make it thread safe . . .

Comment: Then you can [synchronize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Synchronizing your code will have a performance impact, as just one incoming request after the other can enter your code.

BTW, how does the fact, that your code in a libray, prevent you fron having multiple instances of it?

Comment: Here is the basic documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html.

Comment: but synchronizing the code would only help with the issue of the calls coming from a single application and not all the applications, isn't this correct?

Comment: @AndreasMueller I would have a service which is running all the time. Making database changes from a single service thread safe is relatively trivial.

Comment: @GingerHead This is why you have to funnel all the requests through a single service.

Comment: yes but i need to almost change all the application, isn't there any minimal change from the code

Comment: @GingerHead You have to change something which can co-ordinate the changes. It sounds like your only option is to use the the database to do this.  IMHO If your design was right, how you store your data is something you should be able to change easily. esp if you have designed around micro-services.

Comment: let's hope this would help, could you give me hints?

Comment: @GingerHead It will need to be in SQL rather than Java.

Comment: And how is it going to be?

Comment: @GingerHead I am not an expert in programming SQL databases but it would involve stored procedures to do the work I imagine. The fundamental problem is you need to co-ordinate updates somewhere.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree that handling this through a single service is the way to go.  If I understand you correct, you are suggesting to have a single thread to do the computation and the db access? That would work, as it would synchronize the access to the non thread safe computation. However, the OP has to establish an `ExecutorService` with one thread and delegate all incoming calls to it. Or s/he can use something like Akka to build the service to avoid these problems.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Can you explain all this in an answer please??

Comment: @GingerHead What he is proposing would also require a single JVM co-ordinate all access to the database. Any solution in Java would need this.